# Future and Promise mechanism usage

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the `Fututre-Promise` mechanism in `C++`. Here is the code:

```
#include "FuturePromise.h"

void func(std::promise<int>* p) {
    int a = 10, b = 5;
    int result = a + b;
    std::cout << "From inside the Thread...." << std::endl;     p->set_value(result);
}

void func2(std::promise<char*>* p) {
    char str[10] = "Abc";
    std::cout << "From inside the Thread...." << str <<std::endl;
    p->set_value(str);
}

int FP_main() {
    std::promise<char*> p;
    std::future<char*> f = p.get_future();
    std::thread th(func2, &p);
    char* str = f.get();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to output the string returned by the thread function `func` but not getting an expected result (`Abc` string). What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `str` is a local variable, so when does it get destroyed?

Comment: What is `"FuturePromise.h"`? What is `FP_main`? Regardless of that, you are setting the `promise`d value to a pointer to local variable (`str[]`), which gets destroyed as the function ends. You get Undefined Behaviour and likely it manifests as outputting an empty string.

Comment: @Fureeish So the problem is as in classic c++ problem - returning the pointer to the local variable?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are storing a pointer to a local variable in your `promise`, and that goes away when `func2` ends.

A simple fix (as so often with `char *` pointers) is to use `std::promise <std::string>` instead:

```
void func2(std::promise<std::string> *p) {
    const char *str = "Abc";
    std::cout << "From inside the Thread...." << str <<std::endl;
    p->set_value(str);
}

int main() {
    std::promise<std::string> p;
    std::future<std::string> f = p.get_future();
    std::thread th(func2, &p);
    auto str = f.get();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    th.join();
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zE9yKINhstjyes0J)

Comment: So using std::string in the func2 instead of just char* makes the compiler to make a copy of the string instead of passing an address?

Comment: That's right, it puts a copy in your promise ('value semantics').